# FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword takes a lot of time to resolve

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am learning how to implement login/register system in my Flutter app with Firebase (using firebase_auth library). It works but not as expected. The first time to sign-in the "FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword" takes a lot of time to resolve. But once signed-in if I sign-out and sign-in again it goes faster (faster I mean a normal speed).

Main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          // This is the theme of your application.
          //
          // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
          // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
          // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
          // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
          // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
          // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
          // is not restarted.
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const LoginView());
  }
}
```

LoginView.dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState();
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: SizedBox(
        child: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                    ),
                    child: const Text('Sign-out'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            print(snapshot.data);
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                  ),
                  child: const Text('Log In'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: "test@testt.com", password: "testpass");
                      print("Logged");
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                        print('The password provided is too weak.');
                      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
                        print('The account already exists for that email.');
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: the code you are showing looks fine. for me this more sounds like the issue you are having is somewhere else? are you using setstate somewhere? do you have a lot of rebuilds in your app by printing the widgets? this could be a reason. another reason could be that there is something wrong in your auth logic. maybe there is some "hard work" since you are doing another auth state changing action? anyways the snippet you are showing is okay

Comment: I updated the OP with all the code (main.dart and loginview.dart). That is all the code I have.